# Can't Rotate Properly

Tags: transforms

When I try to rotate my starting box it only rotates using the Z-axis even when I press on the Green and Red lines it will not rotate any other way.

Comment: open the N panel (on the right of your 3D view) and check the Transform > Rotation,  maybe you've locked the X and Y rotations?

Comment: Try this - select the cube, press RX the move the mouse. Press RY and move the mouse again.  Press RZ for the Z axis and do the same.  The cube should rotate in all three axis' respectively.